# File Encryption with AES in Java decrtypion in C++ using cryptopp

Tags: java, c++, crypto++

I'm experimenting with Crypto++ library and javax.crypto library.

So what I'm trying to do is... encrypting a text file using AES with CFB mode in java, and then decrypt the encrypted file using crypto++ in C++

here is the java class for encryption

```
public class CryptoUtils {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CFB8/NoPadding";

    Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");

    public static void encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    public static void decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, File inputFile, File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        try {
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey, ivSpec);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);

            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the calling class, with key and iv initialized...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        for(int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            key[i] = 0x0;
            iv[i] = 0x0;
        }

        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");

        String keyStr = new String(key);
        String ivStr = new String(iv);

        File inputFile = new File("target.txt");
        File encryptedFile = new File("target.enc");
        File decryptedFile = new File("target.dec");

        try {
            //CryptoUtils.decrypt(keyStr.getBytes(CHARSET), ivStr.getBytes(CHARSET), encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
            //CryptoUtils.encrypt(keyStr.getBytes(CHARSET), ivStr.getBytes(CHARSET), inputFile, encryptedFile);
            CryptoUtils.encrypt(key, iv, inputFile, encryptedFile);
            //CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, iv, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the C++ code...

```
byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
byte iv[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];

void encrypt64(char* in, char* out) {
    CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

    FileSource f(in, true,
                new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new HexEncoder(new FileSink(out))));
}

void decrypt64(char* in, char* out) {
    CFB_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
    d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

    FileSource f(in, true,
                new HexDecoder(new StreamTransformationFilter(d, new FileSink(out))));
}

int main() {
    memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    decrypt64("target.enc", "target.dec2");

    return 0;
}
```

as its apparent key and iv in both codes are same. still it doesn't work..

I've been at this hours now.. but as I'm a noob in cryptography and cryptography libraries.. so could not find any answer or may be found but didnt got into my head... :/

anyway.. please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it... thanks in advance :)

Comment: In C++, you encode the encrypted data in a hexadecimal representation, in Java you don't. In Java, you specify "NoPadding", which only works if your input data is a multiple of the block size. In C++, I can't see an padding configuration.

Comment: I think you are referencing to the encrypt function... but I do not use that... how ever in decryption function... I use 

FileSource f(in, true, new HexDecoder(new StreamTransformationFilter(d, new FileSink(out))));

which I think... decrypts the data, and then writes the data into file.. so while writing will hex encoding really that matter ?? :/

and here [https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard] I found that... 

Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding") and
CFB_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

are similar.. :/

Comment: Hex encoding converts binary data into ASCII data. The result takes up double the space. Yes, your HexEncoder/HexDecoder does matter. Why do you use it in the first place? And I can't see any information about your input data. So I must assume that "NoPadding" does not work.

Comment: Crypto++ also uses the full block size for the feedback size. You should use `AES/CFB128/...` in Java. More generally, all block ciphers with a feedback loop usually should use the full block size. Otherwise, the key cycles are too small. Also see [block cipher mode feedback cycle](https://www.google.com/search?q=block+cipher+mode+feedback+cycle).